# Card Sliding Transition Animation

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm having an issue with my card slide transition. When I run it through the simulator the first card slides but the rest of the cards don't. Does anyone know why? Since my card image is changing I would think the transition always slides but it's just the first slide. Is there something I'm not noticing even though I'm entering my `if dealtCard` loop?

```swift
struct GameView: View {
    @State var cardDealt = " "
    @State private var dealtCard = false
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Image("white-background")
                .resizable()
                .ignoresSafeArea()
            VStack {
                HStack {
                    Spacer()
                    if dealtCard {
                        Image(cardDealt)
                            .resizable()
                            .cornerRadius(15)
                            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                            .transition(.slide)
                        
                    }
                    Spacer()
                }.shadow(radius: 4)
                
                Spacer()
                HStack {
                    Button {
                        //Action for button
                        withAnimation {
                            deal()
                        }
                        
                    } label:{
                        // How the button look
                        Text("Draw")
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .padding()
                            .background(.black)
                            .cornerRadius(15.0)
                            .font(.system(size:25))
                            .fontWeight(.bold)
                    }
                    Button {
                        //Action for button
                        dismiss()
                    } label:{
                        // How the button look
                        Text("End Game")
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .padding()
                            .background(.black)
                            .cornerRadius(15.0)
                            .font(.system(size:25))
                            .fontWeight(.bold)
                    }
                }.buttonBorderShape(.capsule)
            }
        }
    }

    func deal() {
        let cpuCardValue = Int.random(in:1...50)
        cardDealt = "card" + String(cpuCardValue)
        dealtCard = true
    }
}


struct GameView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        GameView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to implement the image slide animation, you must **first erase the image currently displayed** on the screen and display another image.

You can implement the function with some modifications in your current code.

```swift
struct CardSlideView: View {
    @State var cardDealt = ""
    @State var cardDealt2 = ""  // <--  here
    @State private var dealtCard = false
    @State private var dealtCard2 = false  // <--  here
    
    @ViewBuilder
    func cardImage(_ imageName: String) -> some View {  // <--  here
        Image(imageName)
            .resizable()
            .cornerRadius(15)
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
            .transition(.slide)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Image("white-background")
                .resizable()
                .ignoresSafeArea()
            VStack {
                HStack {
                    Spacer()
                    if dealtCard {  // <--  here
                        cardImage(cardDealt)
                    } else if dealtCard2 {
                        cardImage(cardDealt2)
                    }
                    Spacer()
                }.shadow(radius: 4)
                
                Spacer()
                HStack {
                    Button {
                        //Action for button
                        withAnimation {
                            deal()
                        }
                        
                    } label:{
                        // How the button look
                        Text("Draw")
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .padding()
                            .background(.black)
                            .cornerRadius(15.0)
                            .font(.system(size:25))
                            .fontWeight(.bold)
                    }
                    Button {
                        //Action for button
                        dismiss()
                    } label:{
                        // How the button look
                        Text("End Game")
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .padding()
                            .background(.black)
                            .cornerRadius(15.0)
                            .font(.system(size:25))
                            .fontWeight(.bold)
                    }
                }.buttonBorderShape(.capsule)
            }
        }
    }

    func deal() {  // <--  here
        let cpuCardValue = Int.random(in:1...50)
        let cpuCardValue2 = Int.random(in: 1...50)
        
        cardDealt = "card" + String(cpuCardValue)
        cardDealt2 = "card" + String(cpuCardValue2)
        
        if dealtCard == false && dealtCard2 == false {  // only the first time
            dealtCard = true
        } else {
            dealtCard.toggle()
            dealtCard2.toggle()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Cheolhyun Ill check this later today when I get off work thanks!

Comment: Bro thanks so much man I been trying to figure this out for so long. Thanks a lot this fixed what I needed.